# Primefaces DataTable sortBy EL failed to parse expression

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my facelet I have a PF datatable when I click a header to sort, I get 
`javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{item.null}]`

## `ShippingRoom.xhtml`

```
<f:metadata>
   <o:viewParam name="id" 
     value="#{shippingRoomBean.room}"
     converter="#{shippingRoomConverter}"
     converterMessage="Unknown Shipping Room."
     required="true"
     requiredMessage="Bad request, please use a link from within the system." />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{shippingRoomBean.init}" />
 </f:metadata>

Shipping Room Name: #{shippingRoomBean.name}<br/>
Shipping Room Location: #{shippingRoomBean.location}<br/>

 <p:dataTable id="itemDataTable" var="item" value="#{shippingRoomBean.items}" emptyMessage="No Items Found In This Shipping Room">

<p:column sortBy="item.name" headerText="Item Name"> //attempt1
    #{item.name}
</p:column>
<p:column sortBy="name" headerText="Item Name"> //attempt2 
    #{item.name}
</p:column>
```

## `ShippingRoomBean`

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ShippingRoomBean {

public void init() {
    System.out.println("Initializing ==");
    items = itemRepository.findItemsByShippingRoom(room.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an `<h:form>` tag is required around the data table for the sortBy to work.  Without it I get `javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [#{item.null}]`

```
<h:form>
   <p:dataTable id="itemDataTable" var="item" value="#{shippingRoomBean.items}" emptyMessage="No Items Found In This Shipping Room">
     <p:column sortBy="name" headerText="Item Name">
         #{item.name}
     </p:column>

   </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `attempt1` part and it will be done.

Since PF 4, you cannot have the current object in a `sortBy` attribute, just the related field

```
sortBy="name"
```

instead of

```
sortBy="item.name"
```

Comment: the //attempt is not really in my actual facelets page. I added it here to explain that I tried it (an attempt) both ways "name" and "item.name" neither works.

Comment: I did not understand sorry. You can try to use `<ui:repeat` to iterate on your "items" list and write the 'name' value to see if there is not the same error.